# Dimension in for loop not correct

Tags: r, dimensions

I'm struggling with a problem for two days now and I just don't get it.

```
input <- H_t <- matrix(rep(0,2515), 2515, 4)
H_t[,1]=rnorm(2515)
H_t[,2]=rnorm(2515)
H_t[,3]=rnorm(2515)
H_t[,4]=rnorm(2515)

d=dim(H_t)
Sigma=matrix(0,d[1]*4,4) 
for( i in 2:d[1])
for(k in seq(from=1, to=10057, by=4))
for(l in seq(from=4, to=10060, by=4))
{
Sigma[k:l ,1:4]=cov(H_t[1:i,1:4]) ##here is the problem of dimensions
}
```

The loop should create a rolling window of covariance matrices. This is why I need the Sigma to move by 4. Does R understand the for loop for k and l?

Comment: You 've a semicolon in the last for looping. is that correct? 

for(l in seq(from=4, to=10060, by=4));

Comment: Sorry, no there is none.

Comment: I get an error in the first line... do you want to replace numeric with `rnorm` or something like it?

Comment: Also what covariance are you trying to get? Between the initial matrix (input), subsetted by rows `i-4`  to `i` and what else?

Comment: I want the covariance from H_t from 1:i, so 1:2, 1:3, 1:4.........1:2515. So that you have a 4x4 matrice for each of the 2515 steps.

Comment: Just for clarification, say we are in step `i == 100`, and we are looking at the first column. What you want to have in `Sigma[100, 1]` is the covariance between `H_t[1:100, 1]` and what as a counter part?

Comment: If i==100 => j==397 ,k==400. So Sigma[397:400, 1:4]=cov(H_t[1:100, 1:4]). You need at least two coluns and two rows to calculate the covariance. the columns consist of the log returns of financial assets. E.g. first column, row 397==varinace asset1, 398=cov assets1,2, 399=cov assets1,3, 400==cov assets 1,4. Step i==200, j==401, k=404 => first column, row 401==varinace asset1, 402=cov assets1,2, 403=cov assets1,3, 404==cov assets 1,4 and so on. Hope uyou understand what i mean. @David

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, R understandes the loop for k and l.

Taking your code and adding oppening and closing {} we get:

```
set.seed(101)
input <- H_t <- matrix(rep(0,2515), 2515, 4)
H_t[,1]=rnorm(2515)
H_t[,2]=rnorm(2515)
H_t[,3]=rnorm(2515)
H_t[,4]=rnorm(2515)

d=dim(H_t)
Sigma = matrix(0, d[1]*4, 4)

for(i in 2:d[1]){
  # i <- 2
  for(k in seq(from=1, to=10057, by=4)){
    # k <- 1
    for(l in seq(from=4, to=10060, by=4)){
      # l <- 4
      Sigma[k:l ,1:4] = cov(H_t[1:i,1:4]) ##here is the problem of dimensions
    }
  }
}
```

Side note: Allways good to use set.seed() when using random number generators in examples.

The loop works but results in the following error:

`number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length`

As I understand your code you want to calculate step by step a 4x4 cov matrix, correct?
But the loop tries to save this 4x4 using 
`Sigma[k:l, ]`
It works for the first iteration, i.e. k = 1 and l = 4. But with the the next iteration l takes the value of 8 and now the code says:
`Sigma[1:8, ] = cov(H_t[1:i,1:4])`

Hope this helps.

Edit in response to the comment:

This works for a rolling window backwards looking (window of 4 observations max):

```
n <- 15
set.seed(101)
input <- H_t <- matrix(rep(0,n), n, 4)
H_t[,1] <- rnorm(n)
H_t[,2] <- rnorm(n)
H_t[,3] <- rnorm(n)
H_t[,4] <- rnorm(n)

d <- dim(H_t)
Sigma <- matrix(0, (n-1)*4, 4)

k <- seq(from=1, to=(n-1)*4 - 3, by=4)
length(k)
l <- seq(from=4, to=(n-1)*4, by=4)
length(l)
# start the rolling and calculate the cov backwards looking
for(i in 1:(n-1)){
  present <- i + 1
  past <- present - 3
  if(past < 1) past <- 1
  Sigma[k[i]:l[i], ] = cov(H_t[past:present, 1:4])
}
```

From the comments it now is clear to me it should be a growing window:

```
# start the growing and calculate the cov backwards looking
for(i in 1:(n-1)){
  present <- i + 1
  Sigma[k[i]:l[i], ] = cov(H_t[1:present, 1:4])
}
```

Comment: Yes! I hoped for the second iteration it would take Sigma[5:8, ] and for the third Sigma[9:12, ] and so on. It works if I do it per Hand an fix the values on my own. But why not in the loop?

Comment: It works in the first rows but the last 4x4 matrix should be cov(H_t[1:15,1:4]) this is not the case. I had the same problem and why i changed my code to that above.

Comment: Thus you are not looking for a rolling window, but for an expanding window! Just drop the `past` and put a 1 there.

Comment: Yes, sorry for that mistake!  Thx for your help!